# Is Stripe Web payment instead of in-app purchase in mobile

Tags: stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have an app with Free, Premium and Gold subscription plan. Based on the plan user can access features like filters, messages, likes.

Now, I'm planning to have an web app only for payments using stripe. So, users will directed to web app to pay payments.

Will apple allow this approach or will they insist to use in-app purchase?

I'm little confused here. Need your suggestion here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for Apple Review team, you should reach out to them directly and clarify. Stripe doesn't replace in-app purchases and you need to use Apple's API to perform in-app purchases. See [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) for details

Comment: After having checked with Stripe and other mobile apps like (pacer, Canva and Netflix), I have decided to go with IAP. Stripe integration will be considered as 3rd party payment because my application offers features for premium users. So, I have to use IAP.

Thanks, @qichuan.